# Finding the remaining time when increasing a float value over time [Unity]

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, time

I have a game where a plant is growing from 0% to 100% in a certain time frame (20s in this example), the main code to execute this is in place but id like to have a way to tell how much time remains until it reaches 100% in order to display it.

```cs
public float g;
public float growthstage;
public float timeToGrow = 20; //seconds
public float timeRemaining; //to 100%


void updateGrowth(){
  g += Time.deltaTime / timeToGrow;
  growthstage = Mathf.Lerp(0, 100, g); //from 0% to 100%

  timeRemaining = ???
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather only divide by `timeToGrow` in `Lerp`, then just subtract `g` from `timeToGrow`:

```
g += Time.deltaTime;
growthstage = Mathf.Lerp(0, 100, g/timeToGrow); //from 0% to 100%

timeRemaining = timeToGrow - g;
```

But, if you need to have `g` be the value it is, then you could multiply it by `timeToGrow` before subtracting it from `timeToGrow`. Subjectively, I just find this a little harder to read:

```
g += Time.deltaTime/timeToGrow;
growthstage = Mathf.Lerp(0, 100, g); //from 0% to 100%

timeRemaining = timeToGrow - g * timeToGrow;
```